# Consecutive Integer Divisors

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I stumbled upon this question in my research, and I can't seem to figure out how to prove or disprove it. How do you verify or disprove that an integer n has no common divisors with n+1?

Comment: If $d$ divides two numbers, then it divides their difference.

Comment: Technically, they have exactly two: $1$ and $-1$ ;)

Comment: Did you try anything ?

Comment: This isn't sort of question on which people stumble upon while doing research!!

Comment: Depends on the type of research, perhaps?

Comment: @GTonyJacobs or the deceit of an asker wanting someone to do his/her work for them.

Comment: I'm not here to assume bad faith :)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $d|n$ and $d|n+1$. Then also, $d|(n+1)-n$, which means $d|1$. Thus, $d=\pm 1$.

That's the proof.

Answer (score 1):

If $a|b$ and $a|c$ then $a$ divides any linear combination of $b,c$ i.e. $a|bx+cy$ for all integral values of $x,y$.

In your case wee need to see that if some integer $d|n+1$ and $d|n$ (i.e. $d$ is a common factor of $n+1$ and $n$) then $d|(n+1)\times 1+(n)\times-1\implies d|1\implies d=\pm1$

So, $(n+1,n)=1$ for every value of $n$.

Answer (score 0):

if $a$ is a divisor of both $n+1$ and $n$, then $a$ divides the difference $n+1-n = 1$.
So, a is $+1$ or $-1$.

Answer (score 0):

With the property that $GCD(a,b)=GCD(a,a-b)$

You have $GCD(n,n+1)=GCD(n,1)=1$